# merge sort implementation with arraylisr<String> not sorting

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, mergesort

I am trying to implement a mergeSort function to sort an ArrayList of words that I got from input.txt. (I use the DeleteStopWords() method for this.

The sorted ArrayList that is being returned does not sort properly however I cannot understand why.

Below are my mergSort and merge methods.

```java
public static ArrayList<String> mergeSort(ArrayList<String> listofWords) {

    ArrayList<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String> ();

    if (listofWords.size() == 1) {
        sorted = listofWords;
    } else {
        int middle = listofWords.size() / 2;

        ArrayList<String> leftSide = new ArrayList<String> ();
        ArrayList<String> rightSide = new ArrayList<String> ();

        for (int x = 0; x<middle; x++) {
            leftSide.add(listofWords.get(x));
        }

        for (int x = 0; x<middle; x++) {
            rightSide.add(listofWords.get(x));
        }

        mergeSort(leftSide);
        mergeSort(rightSide);
        sorted = merge(leftSide, rightSide);
    }
    return sorted;
}

public static ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> leftSide, ArrayList<String> rightSide) {

    ArrayList<String> Sortedarray = new ArrayList<String> ();

    int index = 0;
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;

    while (leftIndex<leftSide.size() && rightIndex<rightSide.size()) {

        if ((leftSide.get(leftIndex)).compareTo(rightSide.get(rightIndex))<0) {
            Sortedarray.add(leftSide.get(leftIndex));
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            Sortedarray.add(rightSide.get(rightIndex));
            rightIndex++;
        }

        index++;
    }

    while (leftIndex<leftSide.size()) {
        Sortedarray.add(leftSide.get(leftIndex));
        leftIndex++;
        index++;
    }

    while (rightIndex<rightSide.size()) {
        Sortedarray.add(rightSide.get(rightIndex));
        rightIndex++;
        index++;
    }

    return Sortedarray;
}
```

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does wrong?

Comment: Your `mergeSort` method is returning the sorted result in a different list. When calling recursively, you are ignoring the returned partial result. The problem is here: `mergeSort(leftSide);` and in the following line. I trust you to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems in your code:

1. Firstly, in how you split your lists. Both of them retrieve only the first half of the parameter list. The first `for` should get the first middle elements, while the second the rest of them.
2. Secondly, your `merge` method accepts two lists and returns a new instance which is never assigned to anything in your `mergeSort` method.

Your code should look like this:

```
public static ArrayList<String> mergeSort(ArrayList<String> listofWords) {
    //If the list contains only one element there's nothing to sort
    if (listofWords.size() == 1) {
        return listofWords;
    }

    //Computing the middle index to split the list
    int middle = listofWords.size() / 2;
    ArrayList<String> leftSide = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> rightSide = new ArrayList<>();

    //Adding to the left list the first half
    for (int x = 0; x < middle; x++) {
        leftSide.add(listofWords.get(x));
    }

    //Adding to the right list the second half (the x index should start from where you left)
    for (int x = middle; x < listofWords.size(); x++) {
        rightSide.add(listofWords.get(x));
    }

    //Retrieving the lists and then returning their merge
    leftSide = mergeSort(leftSide);
    rightSide = mergeSort(rightSide);
    return merge(leftSide, rightSide);
}

public static ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> leftSide, ArrayList<String> rightSide) {
    ArrayList<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;

    //Merging the sorted lists into one sorted list
    while (leftIndex < leftSide.size() && rightIndex < rightSide.size()) {
        if (leftSide.get(leftIndex).compareTo(rightSide.get(rightIndex)) < 0) {
            sortedList.add(leftSide.get(leftIndex));
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            sortedList.add(rightSide.get(rightIndex));
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }

    //Adding the remanining elements from the left list
    while (leftIndex < leftSide.size()) {
        sortedList.add(leftSide.get(leftIndex));
        leftIndex++;
    }

    //Adding the remanining elements from the right list
    while (rightIndex < rightSide.size()) {
        sortedList.add(rightSide.get(rightIndex));
        rightIndex++;
    }

    return sortedList;
}
```